# Are there any restrictions on function name calls using GoogleTest for C++?

Tags: googletest

When I call a function using Google Test then is there any restriction like I can not use underscore or any other special character?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can call whatever functions you want. Google Test does not instrument the functions you call.

You shouldn't use any leading or trailing underscores in your *test names* since those are liable to be combined with other names by some of Google Test's macros.